# Object.create vs. new (Class or constructor function)

Tags: javascript, object, new-operator

I am trying to distinguish certain differences in the way of creating new objects. Basically, you can create a new object via object literal ( `const obj = {};` ), as a member of a certain class ( `const obj = new MyObjClass;` ), as a result of a constructor function or by calling `Object.create()`.

Every entity in javascript is an object, even functions, thus everything has `.__proto__` property, but only functions may have (or may not have) `.prototype` property. Child's `.__proto__`  property is equal to it's parent's `.prototype` property. Inside `.prototype` property of such functions you may find `.constructor()` method, which is invoked when you are calling such functions with "`new`" keyword.

This works for classes and constructor functions: you call `new YourFunction()`, then in return you get a new object with it's `__proto__` pointing to parent's `.prototype`,  also `.prototype.constructor()` is invoked, which job is to set properties and methods of the final object.

But if you use `Object.create()`, instead of "`new`" keyword, **is it possible to completely recreate the behavior of "`new`" keyword?**

Here I've tried to recreate it, it seems that it works fine, but when you `console.dir()` every final object, you see rather different results. So..

**What are the core differences between those ways of creating new objects?** Is there something below the surface, or it is just the matter of personal preferences?

```js
const objStorage = {}; // just a storage variable so it is easy to pass it to console.dir()

const obj0 = {  // Declaring an object literal, so that we can pass it to Object.create()
  state: "inside Object.create()",
  showState() { console.log("State: " + this.state) }
}

function Obj1() {  // Making constructor function
  this.state = "inside constructor Function()";
  this.showState = function () { console.log("State: " + this.state) }
}

class Obj2 {  // Making class declaration
  constructor() {
    this.state = "inside Class";
    this.showState = function () { console.log("State: " + this.state) }
  }
}

const obj3 = function(){  // Trying to recreate class functionality, so that it can be used both ways
  let self = {};
  self.state = "inside self-made constructor";
  self.showState = function () { console.log("State: " + this.state) }
  return self
};
obj3.prototype = {};
obj3.prototype.constructor = obj3;

objStorage.a = Object.create(obj0); 
objStorage.b = new Obj1; 
objStorage.c = new Obj2; 
objStorage.d = new obj3.prototype.constructor; 
objStorage.e = Object.create(obj3()); 

objStorage.a.showState(); // State: inside Object.create()
objStorage.b.showState(); // State: inside constructor Function()
objStorage.c.showState(); // State: inside Class
objStorage.d.showState(); // State: inside self-made constructor
objStorage.e.showState(); // State: inside self-made constructor
```

Comment: You're talking of "child" and "parent", but it really should be "instance" and "class".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key difference between [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) and the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator is that, while they both create an object with a prototype chain derived from the prototype object passed, only the `new` operator invokes the constructor with the newly created object applied as `this`, while `Object.create()` does not.

Here's a couple demonstrations of the effects of this difference:

```js
const a = new Array();
const b = Object.create(Array.prototype);

console.log(Array.isArray(a));
console.log(Array.isArray(b));

const c = new Map();
const d = Object.create(Map.prototype);

console.log(c.set('foo', 'bar'));
console.log(d.set('foo', 'bar'));
```

In most cases, there should be no reason to directly use `Object.create()`. The constructor often initializes internal members that are necessary for the object to work as expected.

To answer your other question, no, `new` cannot be completely recreated using `Object.create()`, but it can be by using [`Reflect.construct()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct) instead.

Comment: Patrick, thank you a lot! 
I'll try to dig in `Reflect.construct()` , but overall it now seems that Object.create() is designed for some other purposes.. 
**Object.create() does not invoke the constructor** - the main point, I guess